# Out of range error?

Tags: python, range, output, counting

I am building a function that accepts a string (text) representing  multiple lines and  counts how  many lines  starts  with a  digit (0-9) then returns an integer as the counting result.

I used split to get each individual line and then got the function to check the first index. I am getting an out of range error because some of the test cases have empty spaces as the first index. How do I solve that problem?

Here is the exact error:

### ERROR: test_count_digit_leading_lines_14 (**main**.AllTests)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testerl7.py", line 88, in test_count_digit_leading_lines_14
    def test_count_digit_leading_lines_14 (self): self.assertEqual (count_digit_leading_lines("\t4G\n4G\n4\tG\n\n4000\n55\nsix\n7 days"),5)
  File "/Users/kgreenwo/Desktop/student.py", line 8, in count_digit_leading_lines
    check=newlines[i][0] #check first character in each line
IndexError: string index out of range

---

Here are example outputs:

> count_digit_leading_lines  ("AAA\n1st") → 1 # 2nd line starts  w/ digit    1
>
> count_digit_leading_lines("\t4G\nHz\n") → 0    # 1st line  starts  w/  tab
>
> count_digit_leading_lines  ("0\n0  3\nn4\n") → 2

Here is my current code:

```
def count_digit_leading_lines(text):
count=0
if text == " ":
    return 0
else:
    newlines=text.rstrip('\n').split('\n') #split each line
    for i in range(len(newlines)): 
        if newlines[i] != None:
            check=newlines[i][0] #check first character in each line
            if check.isdigit(): #if 1st is digit 0-9
                count+=1
    return count #return how many times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be string in the newlines array with 0 length. You should remove such elements first:

```
# add this line newlines = [ a for a in newlines if len(a) > 0 ]
# as shown below:


def count_digit_leading_lines(text):
    count=0
    if text == " ":
        return 0
    else:
        newlines = text.rstrip('\n').split('\n') #split each line
        newlines = [ a for a in newlines if len(a) > 0 ]
        for i in range(len(newlines)): 
            check=newlines[i][0] #check first character in each line
            if check.isdigit(): #if 1st is digit 0-9
                count+=1
```